# How can I prove that $\frac{n^2}{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n} \le \frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2} +\dots+ \frac{1}{x_n}$?

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

> How can I prove that $\frac{n^2}{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n} \le \frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2} +\dots+ \frac{1}{x_n}$?

im trying to use AM-GM 
$\sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{x_1} \frac{1}{x_2} \frac{1}{x_3} ..\frac{1}{x_n}}
  \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{{\frac{1}{x_1} +\frac{1}{x_2}+ \frac{1}{x_3}+ ..\frac{1}{x_n}}}{n}$

$ln\sqrt[n]{ \frac{1}{x_1} \frac{1}{x_2} \frac{1}{x_3} ..\frac{1}{x_n}} \le ln \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{1}{x_1} +\frac{1}{x_2}+ \frac{1}{x_3}+ ..\frac{1}{x_n}}$

$ \frac{1}{x_1} \frac{1}{x_2} \frac{1}{x_3} ..\frac{1}{x_n}\le  \sum_{k=1}^n {\frac{1}{x_1} +\frac{1}{x_2}+ \frac{1}{x_3}+ ..\frac{1}{x_n}}$

im not sure is this right or not, however i dont know how to include the $n^2$ in the nominator?
is there also alternative proof using jensen inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jensen's inequality is $\rm{avg~}f(x_i) \le f(\rm{avg~} x)$ (for concave up functions).  So put in $f(z) = 1/z$:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i} \frac{1}{x_i} \le \frac{1}{\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i}$$

Note that this assumes $x_i > 0$.

Comment: thankyou but i'm always confuse, when applying jensen inequality, which one is x ? and what is the average weight? in $f( \sum pf(x)) \ge f(\sum px) $ , what is the average weight or $p$? i know that $ f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: @fiksx You don't need weighted Jensen's for this.  But the weighted version of Jensen's is $$\dfrac{\sum_i w_if(x_i)}{\sum_i w_i} \le f\left(\dfrac{\sum_i w_i x_i}{\sum_i w_i}\right)$$ To get back the version used here just set all the weights equal to one, $w_i = 1$.

Comment: in your answer is the weight = $\frac{1}{n}$? is using the weigted jensen same as your answer?

Comment: @fiksx My answer is using a version of Jensen's without weights, or equivalently, it is using weighted Jensen's with all the weights set to 1, that is $w = \{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \dots\}$  So you get $\frac{1}{\sum_i w_i} = \frac{1}{1 + 1 + 1 \dots} = \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: thankyou but the weight is 1 because it s uniform? so total weight will be $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: @fiksx The equation in my first comment is true for any weight you choose.  We choose weights of 1 because it solves the problem.  If you chose another set of weights you'd get a true but unhelpful statement.  For example if we chose weights = $1/5$ each, we'd get $$\dfrac{\sum_{i} \dfrac 15 \dfrac{1}{x_i}}{\dfrac{1}{5}n} \le \dfrac{1}{\left(\dfrac{\sum_i \dfrac 15 x_i}{\dfrac 15 n}\right)}$$
 which is a true but not helpful statement.

Answer (score 4):

The inequality you are interested in is equivalent $$\frac{1}{\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2} + \dots+ \frac{1}{x_n}}{n}.$$which is just AM-HM inequality.

You can also prove it using CS inequality.

Answer (score 1):

For $x_i>0$ with $i=1,\dots,n$, the given inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{1}{\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}{n}} \le \frac{\frac{1}{x_1}+ \frac{1}{x_2} + \dots+ \frac{1}{x_n}}{n}.$$
Now note that $x\to 1/x$ is convex in $(0,+\infty)$ and use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form).

Comment: thankyou but why the weighted average has to be $\frac{1}{n}$ ? and can i proof using AM-GM?

Comment: Why not? In this case the uniform average works. You should use $AM-HM$ (which can be proved by AM-GM$.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong. Try $x_1\rightarrow0^-$

For positive variables it's true by C-S:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{x_k}\geq\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{x_k\cdot\frac{1}{x_k}}\right)^2=n^2.$$

Also, AM-GM works:
$$\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\sum_{k=1}\frac{1}{x_k}\geq n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k}\cdot n\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}}=n^2.$$
Also, the Tangent Line method helps.

Since our inequality is homogeneous, we can assume that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k=n$ and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}\geq n$$ or
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{x_k}-1\right)\geq0$$ or
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1-x_k}{x_k}+x_k-1\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(x_k-1)^2}{x_k}\geq0$$ and we are done!